# When 澤 has a kunyomi of うるお

Tags: kanji, homophonic-kanji

I'm working on another kanji riddle. 澤 has a kunyomi of うるお (followed by い or す).  I've been digging around to try to figure out what this adjective(?) means.  Swamp-like?

Is this word the same as 潤い? If so, is using 澤 instead of 潤 an older/deprecated usage?

Finally, is 澤い even a commonly used word?

Oh, and I should add it also has a reading of つや.  I don't know what that means either.

Comment: My impression is that the older form 澤 is mostly used in names, while in regular words 沢 is more common.

Answer (score 2):

The sense of うるおい (which is a noun) that 沢 (or 澤) has is that of abundance, as in 沢山【たくさん】, 潤沢【じゅんたく】, or 贅沢【ぜいたく】; and the sense of うるおす that it has is that of favouring or blessing, as in 恩沢【おんたく】or 恵沢【けいたく】.

The sense of つや that 沢 has is that of glossiness, as in 光沢【こうたく】 or 色沢【しきたく】.