# 澤 vs 沢... is the former still in use?

Tags: kanji, jōyō-kanji

[I've asked about 澤 before here on Stack Exchange](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14476/when-%e6%be%a4-has-a-kunyomi-of-%e3%81%86%e3%82%8b%e3%81%8a), but have a follow up question: Is 沢 the modern replacement for 澤? Is 澤 deprecated by the Ministry that decides such matters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Yes, 沢 is the modern replacement (aka 新字体【しんじたい】) form of 澤.
2. The Ministry of Education (文部科学省【もんぶかがくしょう】) is the body that officially determines which characters are and aren't official.
3. 澤 is still used in names, as all 旧字体【きゅうじたい】 (pre-reform) forms of current official characters (常用漢字【じょうようかんじ】) are valid for use in names (人名用漢字【じんめいようかんじ】).
4. [This site](http://www.benricho.org/moji_conv/14_shin_kyu_kanji.html) has a chart showing all of the reformed characters, with the new (新字体) forms on top and old (旧字体) forms on bottom in each row.

Comment: An example of a name that uses 澤: [花澤【はなざわ】香菜【かな】](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%8A%B1%E6%BE%A4%E9%A6%99%E8%8F%9C).

Comment: "文部省" was reorganized and now it's [文部科学省](http://www.mext.go.jp/)

Comment: I work with a 澤村{さわむら}