# Variants of kanji radicals indicating Joyo vs Non-Joyo

Tags: kanji, orthography

I noticed that there is a variant of the 之繞 radical `⻌` which occurs in some words but not others. The variant is `辶` (with an extra stroke). It appears in words like **逢う** and **槌**.
[image]

It turns out that Non-Joyo kanji which use the 之繞 radical are written with the variant `辶` while Joyo kanji use the more common `⻌` - "常用漢字以外は「辶」を用いる" (See details [here](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%B9%8B%E7%B9%9E-538653#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89)).

Are there any other radicals which have variants that are differentiated by Joyo vs Non-Joyo?

Comment: The description is not quite accurate. The one-dot variant is neither "standard" nor "Joyo", it's every *kanji* in Joyo standardised before the 2010 reform. The two-dot variant is more "standard" as it applies to all other *Kanji*, including *Joyo* kanji after 2010. See https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65350/why-is-there-a-difference-between-the-hand-drawn-%e9%81%93-and-the-pc-font-one/65354#65354. Also, neither of these variants apply to handwriting.

Comment: I will comment on the other thread instead. This thread is now redundant.