# "辶" or "⻍", the writing of [之繞]{しん・にょう}

Tags: handwriting

[image]
[image]

I know that for historical reasons, 之繞 in computer systems has two forms:

1. Kanji characters in 当用漢字表 usually use 辶 (一点之繞)
2. Kanji characters outside 当用漢字表 preserve the traditional ⻍ (二点之繞)

However, I can't find anything regarding its handwriting. Are they both acceptable in handwriting?

Comment: The standard handwriting variant is ⻎, not ⻍ or ⻌.

Answer (score 0):

For handwriting, only the 辶 (一点之繞) is used.

For details, see the detailed answer by Drooze [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65350/why-is-there-a-difference-between-the-hand-drawn-%E9%81%93-and-the-pc-font-one/65354#65354)