# Is there one 点 or two in the kanji for まで, viz. 迄?

Tags: kanji

Is there one 点 or two in the kanji for まで, viz. 迄 ?

Some dictionaries show it with one and some show it with two.

The Chinese character only has one and I don't think I've ever seen a Chinese character with two.

Also , is まで ever even written in kanji ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there a difference between the hand drawn 道 and the pc font one?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65350/why-is-there-a-difference-between-the-hand-drawn-%e9%81%93-and-the-pc-font-one)

Comment: @AlexanderZ. Yeah , that answers my question

Comment: 迄 is not a jyouyou kanji, but most people can read it and you will see it from time to time, for example on posters and signs. In daily conversation I would say that people use hiragana.