# What is the relationship between the jinmeiyōkánji/jōyōkánji and level 1 of JIS X 0208?

Tags: kanji

The combined number of jōyōkánji (2,136) and jinmeiyōkánji (863) is 2,999, while the number of kanji in level 1 of JIS X 0208 is 2,965.

What are the characters on the list of 2,999 that aren't on the list of 2,965? Which 漢字 in level 1 of JIS X 0208 are neither 人名用漢字 nor 常用漢字?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/86497/why-are-some-jinmeiyou-kanji-missing-from-jis-1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are some Jinmeiyou kanji missing from JIS 1?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/86497/why-are-some-jinmeiyou-kanji-missing-from-jis-1)

Comment: There's no polite way to say this: no, that doesn't answer my question, as would be obvious to anyone who actually read both my question and that discussion (which I did in fact read before submitting my question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the very helpful answers by Alexander Z. and sundowner, I am now able to answer my questions to my satisfaction:

My first question was: "**What are the characters on the list of 2,999 [the jōyōkánji and jinmeiyōkánji] that aren't on the list of 2,965 [the kanji in level 1 of JIS X 0208]?**"

The answer is the following 331 kanji (298 jinmeiyōkánji and 33 jōyōkánji):

192 jinmeiyōkánji in level 2 of JIS X 0208: 乘 亞 佛 侑 來 俐 傳 僞 價 儉 兒 凉 凛 凰 剩 劍 勁 勳 卷 單 嚴 圈 國 圓 團 壞 壘 壯 壽 奎 奧 奬 孃 實 寢 將 專 峽 崚 巖 巫 已 帶 廣 廳 彈 彌 彗 從 徠 恆 惡 惠 惺 愼 應 懷 戰 戲 拔 拜 拂 搜 搖 攝 收 敍 昊 昴 晏 晄 晝 晨 晟 暉 曉 檜 栞 條 梛 椰 榮 樂 樣 橙 檢 櫂 櫻 盜 毬 氣 洸 洵 淨 渾 滉 漱 滯 澁 澪 濕 煌 燒 燎 燿 爭 爲 狹 默 獸 珈 珀 琥 瑶 疊 皓 盡 眞 眸 碎 祕 祿 禪 禮 稟 稻 穗 穰 穹 笙 粹 絆 綺 綸 縣 縱 纖 羚 翔 飜 聽 脩 臟 與 苺 茉 莊 莉 菫 萠 萬 蕾 藏 藝 藥 衞 裝 覽 詢 諄 謠 讓 賣 赳 轉 迪 逞 醉 釀 釉 鎭 鑄 陷 險 雜 靜 頌 顯 颯 騷 驍 驗 髮 鷄 麒 黎 齊 堯 槇 遙 凜 熙

106 jinmeiyōkánji outside JIS X 0208: 焰 鷗 俠 繫 繡 渚 蔣 醬 蟬 琢 簞 摑 顚 禱 萊 蠟 增 德 橫 瀨 猪 神 祥 福 綠 緖 薰 諸 賴 郞 都 黑 逸 謁 緣 黃 溫 禍 悔 海 渴 漢 器 祈 虛 響 勤 謹 揭 擊 穀 祉 視 煮 社 者 臭 祝 暑 署 涉 狀 節 祖 僧 層 巢 憎 贈 卽 嘆 著 徵 禎
突 難 梅 繁 晚 卑 碑 賓 敏 侮 勉 步 墨 每 祐 欄 虜 淚 類 曆 歷 練 鍊 錄 俱 瘦 吞 寬 廊 朗 懲 plus the one that looks almost like 龍 but has a horizontal rather than vertical first stroke.

30 jōyōkánji in level 2 of JIS X 0208: 丼 傲 刹 哺 喩 嗅 嘲 毀 彙 恣 惧 慄 憬 拉 摯 曖 楷 鬱 璧 瘍 箋 籠 緻 羞 訃 諧 貪 踪 辣 錮

3 jōyōkánji outside JIS X 0208: 塡 剝 頰

For the jōyōkánji , JIS X 0208 has only the official variant 叱. There are also official variants of the following jōyōkánji; none of those variants are in JIS X 0208: 茨 (2 extra variants), 韓 (2), 牙 (2), 栃 (1).

---

My second question was: "**Which 漢字 in level 1 of JIS X 0208 are neither 人名用漢字 nor 常用漢字?**"

The answer is the following 297 kanji:

唖 姶 穐 鯵 姐 虻 飴 袷 吋 嘘 欝 蔚 鰻 荏 嬰 洩 盈 穎 頴 厭 掩 焔 鴛 鴬 鴎 蛾 咳 碍 蛙 蛎 鈎 劃 廓 撹 赫 橿 鰍 鰹 竃 噛 栢 苅 姦 桓 澗 潅 翰 諌 舘 癌 翫 贋 妓 蟻 吃 黍 仇 渠 禦 侠 僑 兇 彊 怯 粁 倶 狗 躯 轡 粂 卦 珪 畦 繋 罫 荊 頚 鹸 姑 狐 菰 鈷 佼 垢 糠 肱 砿 濠 麹 鵠 漉 甑 狛 坤 梱 艮 碕 咋 鮭 匙 鯖 捌 鮫 餐 屍 痔 鴫 宍 蔀 屡 蕊 杓 綬 繍 讐 酋 什 戎 夙 薯 藷 鋤 妾 娼 廠 樵 蒋 醤 鉦 鍾 擾 蝕 疹 塵 靭 笥 趨 椙 脆 蝉 栴 煽 箭 舛 賎 糎 岨 鼠 匝 掻 糟 鎗 詑 柁 騨 岱 腿 鐸 蛸 叩 狸 鱈 箪 蛋 蜘 樗 瀦 苧 凋 諜 銚 鎚 栂 掴 鍔 壷 嬬 吊 剃 碇 鏑 轍 甜 顛 澱 屠 菟 鍍 砺 塘 梼 淘 涛 蕩 鐙 鴇 涜 禿 橡 椴 苫 瀞 噸 呑 乍 畷 迩 韮 葱 撚 廼 嚢 膿 覗 蚤 牌 楳 狽 蝿 矧 粕 駁 硲 櫨 溌 醗 筏 噺 蛤 叛 釆 匪 誹 簸 稗 髭 弼 逼 謬 錨 鋲 蒜 蛭 鰭 斌 埠 弗 鮒 扮 糞 僻 箆 鋪 呆 庖 烹 鉾 吠 穆 釦 鮪 桝 侭 粍 鵡 牝 棉 緬 摸 杢 悶 爺 薮 鑓 愈 揖 涌 猷 熔 慾 莱 葎 燐 苓 聯 婁 榔 牢 篭 聾 蝋 歪 鰐 填 剥 頬 龍

Answer (score 2):

These are the data taken from the [Adobe-Japan1 standard](https://github.com/adobe-type-tools/Adobe-Japan1), according to the 2004 forms of the characters (as opposed to 1990 forms).

Out of 2,136 Jōyō kanji,

4 (four) do not appear in the JIS X 0208 altogether:

> 塡剝頰

The first three did appear in the predecessor of 0208, the JIS C 6226-1978 standard, all in Level 1, at positions 37-22, 39-77, and 43-43 respectively; however, in the 1983 revision, they were replaced by their [extended shinjitai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_shinjitai) correspondences 填, 剥, and 頬. Instead of , 叱 has always been present in 0208. When extending the Jōyō in 2010, however, the three unsimplified forms and  were taken in Jōyō, despite not appearing in 0208.

2,102 characters appear in Level 1 of 0208. Finally, 30 characters are in Level 2:

> 丼傲刹哺喩嗅嘲毀彙恣惧慄憬拉摯曖楷鬱璧瘍箋籠緻羞訃諧貪踪辣錮

Out of 863 Jinmeiyō kanji,

566 are on Level 1:

> 娃阿逢葵茜渥旭葦芦梓斡絢綾鮎或粟庵按鞍杏伊夷惟謂亥郁磯溢鰯允胤蔭烏迂卯鵜窺丑碓姥厩瓜閏噂云叡曳瑛榎堰奄燕苑薗於甥襖荻桶牡伽嘉珂禾茄蝦嘩迦霞俄峨臥駕廻恢魁晦芥蟹凱鎧浬馨笠樫梶恰叶椛樺鞄兜蒲鴨茅萱粥侃柑竿莞巌雁嬉毅稀徽祇誼掬鞠桔橘砧杵汲灸笈鋸亨匡卿喬蕎饗尭桐欣欽禽芹衿玖矩駈喰寓櫛釧屑沓窪隈栗鍬袈祁圭慧桂戟訣倦喧捲牽硯絃諺乎糊袴胡跨伍吾梧檎瑚醐鯉倖宏巷庚弘昂晃杭浩紘腔膏閤鴻劫壕轟忽惚此昏些叉嵯瑳裟坐哉犀砦冴堺榊肴鷺朔窄笹薩皐錆晒撒燦珊纂讃仔孜斯獅爾而蒔汐竺雫悉篠偲柴縞紗勺灼錫惹洲蒐輯峻竣舜駿楯淳醇曙渚恕哨嘗庄捷昌梢樟湘菖蕉裳鞘丞杖穣埴燭晋榛秦壬訊諏厨逗翠錐錘瑞嵩雛菅頗雀摺棲栖蹟碩尖撰穿銑閃噌曾楚疏蘇叢宋惣槍漕綜聡蒼其揃舵楕陀苔黛鯛醍鷹瀧啄托琢茸凧只辰巽竪辿樽坦歎湛耽檀弛智馳筑註猪喋寵帖暢牒脹蝶槌槻佃柘辻蔦綴椿紬悌挺梯汀禎蹄鄭釘鼎擢纏兎堵杜砥套宕嶋燈祷董撞萄鳶寅酉惇敦沌遁凪薙灘捺楢馴楠汝賑廿濡禰祢乃之埜巴播杷琶芭盃煤這秤萩柏箔曝莫函肇筈幡畠鳩塙隼挽磐蕃庇斐緋樋枇毘琵柊疋彦菱畢桧紐彪瓢豹廟彬瀕冨斧芙撫葡蕪楓葺蕗淵吻焚頁碧瞥篇娩鞭圃甫輔戊菩峯捧朋萌蓬鋒鳳鵬卜殆幌哩槙柾鱒亦俣沫迄麿蔓巳箕湊蓑稔牟椋姪孟蒙儲勿尤籾貰匁也耶靖佑宥柚祐邑輿傭楊耀蓉遥淀螺洛蘭李裡掠劉溜琉龍亮凌梁稜諒遼淋琳鱗麟伶嶺怜玲憐漣煉簾蓮魯櫓狼禄肋倭鷲亙亘詫藁蕨椀碗

192 are on Level 2:

> 乘亞佛侑來俐傳僞價儉兒凉凛凰剩劍勁勳卷單嚴圈國圓團壞壘壯壽奎奧奬孃實寢將專峽崚巖巫已帶廣廳彈彌彗從徠恆惡惠惺愼應懷戰戲拔拜拂搜搖攝收敍昊昴晏晄晝晨晟暉曉檜栞條梛椰榮樂樣橙檢櫂櫻盜毬氣洸洵淨渾滉漱滯澁澪濕煌燒燎燿爭爲狹默獸珈珀琥瑶疊皓盡眞眸碎祕祿禪禮稟稻穗穰穹笙粹絆綺綸縣縱纖羚翔飜聽脩臟與苺茉莊莉菫萠萬蕾藏藝藥衞裝覽詢諄謠讓賣赳轉迪逞醉釀釉鎭鑄陷險雜靜頌顯颯騷驍驗髮鷄麒黎齊堯槇遙凜熙

Note that the last 5 here were appended to 0208 in 1982 and 1990.

105 are outside 0208:

> 焰鷗俠繫繡渚蔣醬蟬琢簞摑顚禱萊蠟增德橫瀨猪神祥福綠緖薰諸賴郞都黑逸謁緣黃溫禍悔海渴漢器祈虛響勤謹揭擊穀祉視煮社者臭祝暑署涉狀節祖僧層巢憎贈卽嘆著徵禎突難梅繁晚卑碑賓敏侮勉步墨每祐欄虜淚類曆歷練鍊錄俱瘦吞寬廊朗懲

Out of 514 [National Language Council kanji](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Uncommon_kanji) which are neither Jōyō nor Jinmeiyō,

134 are on Level 1:

> 虻飴鰻嬰洩穎厭蛾咳蛙廓橿鰹姦桓澗翰癌翫贋妓蟻吃仇渠僑怯狗粂珪畦荊姑狐菰垢糠濠鵠漉甑鮭鯖捌鮫餐屍痔杓綬讐酋薯藷鋤妾娼鉦鍾擾蝕疹塵笥趨脆煽箭鼠腿鐸蛸叩狸蛋蜘瀦諜銚鎚吊剃碇轍澱屠淘蕩禿苫瀞韮葱撚膿覗蚤牌狽粕駁筏噺蛤叛誹稗髭逼謬蛭鮒扮糞僻呆庖鉾吠鵡牝悶爺鑓愈涌猷熔燐榔牢聾歪鰐

360 are on Level 2:

> 乖于亢仄佇侘儘俤俯偈冑冤几剋匈卉叟曼吼呵咎呟呻咄咸咬咤哭啜啖唸喀喘啼嗚嗟嗜嘔嘴嚥囁囃囀址埃埒墟壙壺奢奸娑婉娶媚嬌孕孵宦宸寥尹屁屎屹峙崗嵌帚帛帷幟廂廬彎彷徊徘恍悍悸愕憚憑憫罹懺懼戌截戮扁抉抒拗拿拮捏掟揆揉揶揄攪撥攀攘攣敲斃旱晰暈曠曰朦朧杣枡柩檮梵棘椒棹楔楮楡槃榜榴檻櫃櫟欅殷毫毯沁泄洒浙濤涅涵涸滓漑灌漿滲瀑濾瀾炒炬炸焉熾燵爛爬狡猥瑕甕甦疆疇疵疽疸疼疱痒痙痰痺瘡瘤瘻癬皺盂眩睨睫睾瞑瞞瞰瞼砒磋礫祀祠祟祓禊穢窩竈竦筵箒箏篆篝簀籬紮絨絣綽罠翅翳耆聊聘聚聳肛胚胱脛腋隋脾腑腱膀膠膣膵臀臂臍臘舅舐艘芒芻苞茫莢荼萼蓼薨蕭薔藪薇蘆虔蛉蠣蛛蜀蜃蜻蝸蠅雖蟇衙袁袂袢裔褌褥襞襦襷訛訝訶誅誦諫諤諱謔諷謗謳譚賤賽贄贅趙趾跏跋踵蹊躁躇躊躬軋轢邇逍遽邁邱鄙鈔鉗鉤鋏鍼閨閻閾闊闍陝隕隧雉霰靄勒靱鞋韋竟頸頷頽顆飫饉饅饒騙髷髻鬘鬚鬢魏鮨鰺鰓鰊鴉鶯鸚鸞靡齟齬

20 are absent from 0208:

> 啞嚙軀鹼麴屢搔驒瀆囊潑醱麵屛攢噓﨟鄧姸幷

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, without which the other answer wouldn't have been corrected. This means the two sets of 2,999 and 2,965 have 2,668 kanji in common, with 297 kanji in level 1 of JIS X 0208 being neither jinmeiyōkánji nor jōyōkánji, and with 331 jōyōkánji/jinmeiyōkánji missing in level 1 of JIS X 0208 (34 jōyōkánji and 297 jinmeiyōkánji).

Comment: It's interesting to note that in _handwriting_, forms corresponding to 填 頬 剥 are officially preferred to forms corresponding to the official printed forms 塡 剝 頰, and a form corresponding to 叱 is officially allowed next to a form corresponding to the official printed form   (and a third form): https://www.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/sisaku/joho/joho/kijun/naikaku/pdf/joyokanjihyo_20101130.pdf.

Comment: Actually, looking further into the matter, it turns out that 叱 has a different status from 填 剥 頬. According to the official 常用漢字表, 叱 is actually a fully official printed variant of . There are also seven other official printed variants of four other characters.

Comment: For the numbers, this has the following consequences: While there are 2,136 jōyōkánji, there are 2,144 official jōyōkánji glyphs, for a total of 3,007 official jōyōkánji/jinmeiyōkánji glyphs. Of these glyphs, 2,669 are found in JIS X 0208, with 296 kanji glyphs in level 1 of JIS X 0208 being neither jinmeiyōkánji glyphs nor jōyōkánji glyphs, and with 338 jōyōkánji/jinmeiyōkánji glyphs not being part of JIS X 0208 (41 jōyōkánji glyphs and 297 jinmeiyōkánji glyphs).

Comment: Counting any official variant of a jōyōkánji (and not counting variants that are acceptable only for technical reasons), the 2,965 JIS X 0208 level 1 kanji include official printed versions of 2,669 of the 2,999 jōyōkánji/jinmeiyōkánji, with 296 kanji in level 1 of JIS X 0208 being neither jinmeiyōkánji nor jōyōkánji, and with 330 jōyōkánji/jinmeiyōkánji missing in level 1 of JIS X 0208 (33 jōyōkánji and 297 jinmeiyōkánji).

Comment: Looking _even_ further into this mind-blowingly complicated matter, inspired by the newly added final paragraph of the other answer, it turns out that the form of 龍 in the official jinmeiyōkánji list has a horizontal first stroke (despite the official jōyōkánji list giving the traditional form of 竜 as 龍 with a vertical first stroke). Assuming 龍 with a vertical first stroke is an incorrect jinmeiyōkánji, we get _yet_ new numbers:

Comment: While there are 2,136 jōyōkánji, there are 2,144 official jōyōkánji glyphs, for a total of 3,007 official jōyōkánji/jinmeiyōkánji glyphs. Of these glyphs, 2,668 are found in JIS X 0208, with 297 kanji glyphs in level 1 of JIS X 0208 being neither jinmeiyōkánji glyphs nor jōyōkánji glyphs, and with 339 jōyōkánji/jinmeiyōkánji glyphs not being part of JIS X 0208 (41 jōyōkánji glyphs and 298 jinmeiyōkánji glyphs).

Comment: Counting any official variant of a jōyōkánji (and not counting variants that are acceptable only for technical reasons), the 2,965 JIS X 0208 level 1 kanji include official printed versions of 2,668 of the 2,999 jōyōkánji/jinmeiyōkánji, with 297 kanji in level 1 of JIS X 0208 being neither jinmeiyōkánji nor jōyōkánji, and with 331 jōyōkánji/jinmeiyōkánji missing in level 1 of JIS X 0208 (33 jōyōkánji and 298 jinmeiyōkánji).

Answer (score 1):

I took the diff of [JIS level 1](http://www13.plala.or.jp/bigdata/jis_1.html) and <strike>[Jinmeiyokanji (pdf)](http://kanji.zinbun.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Eyasuoka/publications/2019-07-26.pdf)</strike> [Wikipedia's list](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BB%98%E9%8C%B2:%E4%BA%BA%E5%90%8D%E7%94%A8%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7). (Neither is of the government, but at least I confirmed the numbers are correct.)

The things are not that simple, possibly the linked question gives some explanation. I found also [this](https://seiai.ed.jp/sys/text/csd/cf14/c14a080.html).

Notation:

- JIS = 2965 chars, Joyo = 2136 chars, Jinmei = 863 chars, JinmeiFull = Joyo + Jinmei 2999 chars
- X - Y : In X and not in Y

JIS - JinmeiFull (293) [Edit] I checked (using [this list of 常用漢字](https://www.benricho.org/kanji/kyoikukanji/check-jyoyo-kanji-ichiran.html)) that the list below coincides with the set in the question *In JIS and neither in Jinmei nor in Joyo*.

[
"唖",
"姶",
"穐",
"鯵",
"姐",
"虻",
"飴",
"袷",
"吋",
"嘘",
"欝",
"蔚",
"鰻",
"荏",
"嬰",
"洩",
"盈",
"穎",
"頴",
"厭",
"掩",
"焔",
"鴛",
"鴬",
"鴎",
"蛾",
"咳",
"碍",
"蛙",
"蛎",
"鈎",
"劃",
"廓",
"撹",
"赫",
"橿",
"鰍",
"鰹",
"竃",
"噛",
"栢",
"苅",
"姦",
"桓",
"澗",
"潅",
"翰",
"諌",
"舘",
"癌",
"翫",
"贋",
"妓",
"蟻",
"吃",
"黍",
"仇",
"渠",
"禦",
"侠",
"僑",
"兇",
"彊",
"怯",
"粁",
"倶",
"狗",
"躯",
"轡",
"粂",
"卦",
"珪",
"畦",
"繋",
"罫",
"荊",
"頚",
"鹸",
"姑",
"狐",
"菰",
"鈷",
"佼",
"垢",
"糠",
"肱",
"砿",
"濠",
"麹",
"鵠",
"漉",
"甑",
"狛",
"坤",
"梱",
"艮",
"碕",
"咋",
"鮭",
"匙",
"鯖",
"捌",
"鮫",
"餐",
"屍",
"痔",
"鴫",
"宍",
"蔀",
"屡",
"蕊",
"杓",
"綬",
"繍",
"讐",
"酋",
"什",
"戎",
"夙",
"薯",
"藷",
"鋤",
"妾",
"娼",
"廠",
"樵",
"蒋",
"醤",
"鉦",
"鍾",
"擾",
"蝕",
"疹",
"塵",
"靭",
"笥",
"趨",
"椙",
"脆",
"蝉",
"栴",
"煽",
"箭",
"舛",
"賎",
"糎",
"岨",
"鼠",
"匝",
"掻",
"糟",
"鎗",
"詑",
"柁",
"騨",
"岱",
"腿",
"鐸",
"蛸",
"叩",
"狸",
"鱈",
"箪",
"蛋",
"蜘",
"樗",
"瀦",
"苧",
"凋",
"諜",
"銚",
"鎚",
"栂",
"掴",
"鍔",
"壷",
"嬬",
"吊",
"剃",
"碇",
"鏑",
"轍",
"甜",
"顛",
"澱",
"屠",
"菟",
"鍍",
"砺",
"塘",
"梼",
"淘",
"涛",
"蕩",
"鐙",
"鴇",
"涜",
"禿",
"橡",
"椴",
"苫",
"瀞",
"噸",
"呑",
"乍",
"畷",
"迩",
"韮",
"葱",
"撚",
"廼",
"嚢",
"膿",
"覗",
"蚤",
"牌",
"楳",
"狽",
"蝿",
"矧",
"粕",
"駁",
"硲",
"櫨",
"溌",
"醗",
"筏",
"噺",
"蛤",
"叛",
"釆",
"匪",
"誹",
"簸",
"稗",
"髭",
"弼",
"逼",
"謬",
"錨",
"鋲",
"蒜",
"蛭",
"鰭",
"斌",
"埠",
"弗",
"鮒",
"扮",
"糞",
"僻",
"箆",
"鋪",
"呆",
"庖",
"烹",
"鉾",
"吠",
"穆",
"釦",
"鮪",
"桝",
"侭",
"粍",
"鵡",
"牝",
"棉",
"緬",
"摸",
"杢",
"悶",
"爺",
"薮",
"鑓",
"愈",
"揖",
"涌",
"猷",
"熔",
"慾",
"莱",
"葎",
"燐",
"苓",
"聯",
"婁",
"榔",
"牢",
"篭",
"聾",
"蝋",
"歪",
"鰐"
]

Jinmei - JIS (297)

[
"侑",
"俠",
"俐",
"俱",
"凜",
"凛",
"凰",
"勁",
"吞",
"堯",
"奎",
"崚",
"巖",
"巫",
"已",
"彗",
"徠",
"惺",
"摑",
"昊",
"昴",
"晏",
"晄",
"晟",
"晨",
"暉",
"檜",
"栞",
"梛",
"椰",
"槇",
"橙",
"櫂",
"毬",
"洸",
"洵",
"渚",
"渾",
"滉",
"漱",
"澪",
"焰",
"煌",
"熙",
"燎",
"燿",
"猪",
"珈",
"珀",
"琢",
"琥",
"瑶",
"皓",
"眸",
"祐",
"禱",
"祿",
"禎",
"稟",
"穰",
"穹",
"笙",
"簞",
"絆",
"綺",
"綸",
"繫",
"繡",
"羚",
"翔",
"脩",
"苺",
"茉",
"莉",
"菫",
"萠",
"萊",
"蔣",
"蕾",
"蟬",
"蠟",
"詢",
"諄",
"赳",
"迪",
"逞",
"遙",
"醬",
"釉",
"頌",
"顚",
"颯",
"驍",
"鷗",
"麒",
"黎",
"亞",
"惡",
"爲",
"逸",
"榮",
"衞",
"謁",
"圓",
"緣",
"應",
"櫻",
"奧",
"橫",
"溫",
"價",
"禍",
"悔",
"海",
"壞",
"懷",
"樂",
"渴",
"卷",
"陷",
"寬",
"漢",
"氣",
"祈",
"器",
"僞",
"戲",
"虛",
"峽",
"狹",
"響",
"曉",
"勤",
"謹",
"勳",
"薰",
"惠",
"揭",
"鷄",
"藝",
"擊",
"縣",
"儉",
"劍",
"險",
"圈",
"檢",
"顯",
"驗",
"嚴",
"廣",
"恆",
"黃",
"國",
"黑",
"穀",
"碎",
"雜",
"祉",
"視",
"兒",
"濕",
"實",
"社",
"者",
"煮",
"壽",
"收",
"臭",
"從",
"澁",
"獸",
"縱",
"祝",
"暑",
"署",
"緖",
"諸",
"敍",
"將",
"祥",
"涉",
"燒",
"奬",
"條",
"狀",
"乘",
"淨",
"剩",
"疊",
"孃",
"讓",
"釀",
"神",
"眞",
"寢",
"愼",
"盡",
"粹",
"醉",
"穗",
"瀨",
"齊",
"靜",
"攝",
"節",
"專",
"戰",
"纖",
"禪",
"祖",
"壯",
"爭",
"莊",
"搜",
"巢",
"裝",
"僧",
"層",
"瘦",
"騷",
"增",
"憎",
"藏",
"贈",
"臟",
"卽",
"帶",
"滯",
"單",
"嘆",
"團",
"彈",
"晝",
"鑄",
"著",
"廳",
"徵",
"聽",
"懲",
"鎭",
"轉",
"傳",
"都",
"盜",
"稻",
"德",
"突",
"難",
"拜",
"賣",
"梅",
"髮",
"拔",
"繁",
"晚",
"卑",
"祕",
"碑",
"賓",
"敏",
"侮",
"福",
"拂",
"佛",
"勉",
"步",
"墨",
"飜",
"每",
"萬",
"默",
"彌",
"藥",
"與",
"搖",
"樣",
"謠",
"來",
"賴",
"覽",
"欄",
"虜",
"凉",
"綠",
"淚",
"壘",
"類",
"禮",
"曆",
"歷",
"練",
"鍊",
"郞",
"朗",
"廊",
"錄"
]

Joyo - JIS (30 + 4)

[
"丼",
"傲",
"刹",
"哺",
"喩",
"嗅",
"嘲",
"毀",
"彙",
"恣",
"惧",
"慄",
"憬",
"拉",
"摯",
"曖",
"楷",
"鬱",
"璧",
"瘍",
"箋",
"籠",
"緻",
"羞",
"訃",
"諧",
"貪",
"踪",
"辣",
"錮"
] + 塡 剝  頰

**[Edit]**

A comment regarding 4 characters in Alexander's answer. All four seem to have their variant 填 剥 叱 頬 in Joyo (at least in the list linked in this answer). That's why they don't appear above.

The first part of Alexander Z's answer is consistent with the above counts: 192 Level 2 + 105 outside JIS2080 = 297 in Jinmei - JIS. As for the second part, I have no idea what 514 characters fit in the above.

**[Second Edit]**

I added  塡 剝  頰 to Joyo - JIS.

I didn't edit the other set. The variants 填 剥 叱 頬 are acceptable in Joyo as mentioned in [this quora answer](https://jp.quora.com/ya-nado-2010-nen-jouyoukanji-omote-ni-tsuika-sa-re-ta-kyuu-jitai-no-kanji-ha-shin-jitai-no-itai-ji-wo-shi-e-ba-ii-desu-ka), citing a guideline from Agency for Cultural Affairs.

The point is that Joyo kanji is not simply a set of glyphs. A kanji has [variants](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AD%97%E4%BD%93#%E7%95%B0%E4%BD%93%E5%AD%97), sometimes many of them, and these are not only about Shinjitai (simplified) / Kyujitai (nonsimplified). The guideline cited above states in which cases identifications of kanjis are possible. This means, as a set of glyphs, Joyo kanji contains more than those listed.

On the other hand, it may be fair to consider JIS as a set of glyphs - hence the addition.

===

An example I found interesting is 竜 / 龍. Both are in Jinmei; the latter is usually considered to be *the* nonsimplified version of the former. But according to [this](https://dictionary.sanseido-publ.co.jp/column/%E7%AC%AC2%E5%9B%9E%E3%80%8C%E7%AB%9C%E3%80%8D%E3%81%A8%E3%80%8C%E9%BE%8D%E3%80%8D), the *correct* one (in the sense of the glyph originally published) is the 龍 with the first stroke horizontal (see the link).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: I take it there are no 常用漢字 that aren't in level 1 of JIS X 0208?

Comment: Actually, doing the maths, it turns out that the first list implies the set of 2,999 and the set of 2,965 have 2,658 kanji in common, while the second list implies they have 2,659 kanji in common. That means there is one 常用漢字 that isn't in level 1 of JIS X 0208.

Comment: Copying from PDF doesn't seem to work sometimes, so I used Wikipedia instead. I guess the diff should be correct as long as the source lists are correct. I'm not sure the above is consistent with Alexander Z's answer, but not that variants are not taken into account at all.

Comment: @user46840 I added Joyo - JIS for your additional question.

Comment: @sundowner The second list, "In Jinmei and not in JIS", would need to be replaced with "In Jinmei or Joyo and not in JIS" to answer my original question.

Comment: @user46840 Updated. But just to make sure, by Jinmei you mean 863 characters, right?

Comment: @sundowner Yes.

Comment: @sundowner It would appear per Alexander Z.'s answer that 塡剝頰 are missing in the "Joyo - JIS" list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128453/discussion-between-sundowner-and-user46840).

Comment: Since you're not replying in chat: The 常用漢字 list linked in your answer is incorrect in having 填 剥 叱 頬; it should have 塡 剝  頰 instead. This means that 填 剥 叱 頬 should be added to the "JIS - JinmeiFull" list, while 塡 剝  頰 should be added to the "Joyo - JIS" list.

Comment: Sorry I missed. Please see the edit. I'm afraid I am not fully knowledgeable on the matter, so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: Looking further into the matter, it turns out that 叱 has a different status from 填 剥 頬. According to the official 常用漢字表, 叱 is actually a fully official printed variant of . Meanwhile, 填 剥 頬 have only the same status as variants of 淫 葛 僅 煎 詮 嘲 捗 溺 賭 箸 蔽 (list from Wikipedia; the official document mentions only 頬 賭 剥 as examples): they are acceptable for technical reasons only. I think it's misleading to say that 填 剥 頬 are 常用漢字 found in JIS X 0208 when the only reason they are acceptable as 常用漢字 is that their correct forms aren't found in standards like JIS X 0208.

Comment: To your other addition: checking the official lists, it turns out that the 人名用漢字 list has the form with the first line horizontal, while the 常用漢字 list has 龍 as the traditional form.

Comment: Well, it just depends on how you see it, but 常用漢字 defines what kanjis are acceptable in official documents, and those variants are defined to be acceptable in the guideline.

Comment: We'll have to disagree, then. 常用漢字表 defines official forms for all the 常用漢字 . The fact that the document expresses acceptance of the use of unofficial forms when unavoidable doesn't mean the difference between official and unofficial is irrelevant. The forms 填 剥 頬 are officially incorrect.

Comment: Just my last comment: I generally do not think that anything any government does is  that precise./reasonable.  A character is handwritten originally, and deciding _the_ form of any character is not very realistic (a and _a_ are different). Putting character forms aside, there are lots of controversies in 常用漢字. One thing worth noting (not directly relevant to the status of the four characters) would be that a committee member on deciding 当用漢字 had a policy that "difference by one stroke" does not count  according to [a blog post](https://koikekaisho.hatenadiary.org/entry/20120201/1328061513).

Comment: People may have different opinions on the appropriateness of defining official forms for 漢字, but that doesn't change the fact that 常用漢字表 does just that. The existence of controversies in relation to the 常用漢字 does not change the fact that there is but one official 常用漢字 document, and that it contains a fixed set of rulings, which can then be described. 常用漢字表 doesn't even mention the form 填.