# Is "夛" an alias for "多"?

Tags: word-choice, kanji

Is "夛" an alias for "多"?
For example, I suppose that "夛田" is one of family names in Japan, is it  the same as "多田"?

Comment: I'd be inclined to guess it's shorthand for 夢.

Comment: @istrasci The shorthand for 夢 is 梦.

Answer (score 3):

While dictionaries say 夛 is a variant of 多, there are virtually no occasion where they are interchangeable. In fact, I have just learned 夛 is a variant of 多. (They look so different!)

When you construct a normal sentence, you always have to use 多, which is a very basic kanji all children learn at school. If you used 夛い, people would just think you made some strange mistake.

夛 is a rare kanji which is found only in some family names. 夛 is not a 常用漢字, and it is not even included in 人名用漢字, which means it is illegal to name a new baby using 夛. FWIW, the *only* person I know who has 夛 in their name is [Ken Kutaragi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Kutaragi).

In general, you should not change the appearance of kanji used in person names. 久夛良木 is 久夛良木 and not 久多良木. 多田 is not 夛田. For details, see: [Use of 旧字体 in Japanese names](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30507/5010)

Answer (score 1):

[夛 is a variant of 多.](http://kanji.jitenon.jp/kanjim/6157.html) 音 and 訓's readings are respectively タ and おお・い. So both kanji are same.